# Entity framework error "Entity type is not mapped."

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

We are using Entity Framework in our project and I have an entity that I built in my model. I then have a function import that uses a stored procedure. The method created by the function import is supposed to return a collection of the custom entity I created.

> The problem is that I get an error when I build that says "The entity type 'someentity' is not mapped.

What does this mean? Is it upset because the entity does not have an underlying data store? It doesn't need one, the function import returns instances of this entity and I have no need to update, edit, or insert entities of this type.

The function import works great and returns a collection of my entity as desired, but this error is annoying. Though the error list lists it as a compile error, it does not actually stop the solution from compiling.

### Update

If I open the EDMX in the XML editor and double click the error in the error list it highlights this chunk of XML in red:

```
   <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="KlasEntitiesStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="KlasEntities">
      <EntitySetMapping Name="VendorBriefs"><EntityTypeMapping TypeName="KlasEntityDataModel.VendorBrief"><MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="ev_VendorBriefs">
        <ScalarProperty Name="VendorBriefID" ColumnName="VendorBriefID" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="Title" ColumnName="Title" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="Link" ColumnName="Link" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="LinkText" ColumnName="LinkText" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="BriefPath" ColumnName="BriefPath" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="Description" ColumnName="Description" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="IsActive" ColumnName="IsActive" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="DisplayOrder" ColumnName="DisplayOrder" />
      </MappingFragment></EntityTypeMapping></EntitySetMapping>
      <FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="SearchForVendorProductByKlasID" FunctionName="KlasEntities.Store.ev_ds_Products_SearchByKLASID" />
    </EntityContainerMapping>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each entity must be mapped either to QueryView or to database table / defining query. You can't create the entity which is not mapped at all. If you want to define result of function import which is not mapped in your model you must define your `VendorBrief` as complex type.

Comment: [This was exactly what I needed to do.](http://www.codetunnel.com/blog/post/53/how-to-map-a-stored-procedure-to-an-entity-in-entity-framework-4) Thank you.

Comment: @AlexFord and that link broke :(  Is this a similar one?: http://sanganakauthority.blogspot.com/2013/07/the-function-import-cannot-be-executed.html

Comment: @Termato Here you go: http://www.codetunnel.com/how-to-map-a-stored-procedure-to-an-entity-in-entity-framework-4/

Answer (score 8):

1. Open the datamodel (edmx file)
2. Right-click in the datamodel and select Model Browser
3. In the model browser window go to Function Imports and delete the appropriate items.

Answer (score 7):

Try to open your Entity file diagram, the .edmx. And then delete all the tables using DEL. And then right click inside the diagram and select Update Model from Database.

The Visual Studio is a little bugged in this stuff.

Comment: Or if you do not have data in the database, you can do the opposite: `Update Database from Model`. That should solve the problem too.

Comment: I think both of you are misunderstanding. This entity is not mapped to the database. This entity only exists in the EDMX and is not supposed to be mapped. The only time it's used is when the function import needs a place to dump the results of the stored procedure. It does this in the form of a collection of this custom entity type.

Comment: Six years later, mid-2017, and this bug is still alive and kicking in "VS2015 Update 3".  I know it's not supported, but "LINQ to SQL" just always *worked*.  Every time.....

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried representing it using a Complex Type instead of an Entity and mapping to that instead?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I was having this issue as well but the error just went away when I opened the edmx in the XML editor.  I tried all variations of removing tables then updating the edmx.

The other odd thing I was having, the error was referring to a relationship between two tables but when I double clicked on the error message it highlighted another table other than the two it was referring to.

Comment: This answer is too vague to be meaningful to others.

Comment: Too vague? What's too vague? You open the file in the XML editor and it works.  In other words, it's a VS editor issue.